# Find the 'rigidity per mass' of beam profiles from second moment of area, length and density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, moment-of-inertia, structural-beam

> Calculate the “rigidity per mass”, i.e. the ratio of the second moment of area and the
>   mass of a beam (length , density ) for the following cross-sections:
>   [image]

I know how to get the second moment of inertia, but I'm not sure about what I'm supposed to do in the second part of the question. How do I get the ratio and how do I use length and density for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should multiply the area $A$ (m2)  of the cross section with the density $d$ (kg/m3)  of the material of the beam. That result will give the mass per meter (kg/m) of a beam. One has to multiply this value with the length $l$ of the beam in order to calculate it's mass.

Basically you are asked for the two properties as marked in the following table:

[image]

**After calculating the values $G$ and $I$ then the  “rigidity per mass” as expressed in your exercise is simply the ratio $I/G$.**

Comment: So I just divide the second moment of inertia by the mass? Is that the ratio they are looking for or is there something else?

Comment: No , just multiply A and d. That will give you the ratio kg/m of the beam.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. How does that get me the ratio of the second moment of area and the mass of the beam? I have to calculate the second moment of area first, right? I don't know how to go from there to relate the second moment of area to the mass to get the ratio.

Comment: They ask you for two different things. First to calculate the 'second moment of area' that you said you can , and second the ratio of ' the mass of a beam'. They are not related .

Comment: Ooh okay, I thought they meant the 'rigidity per mass' was the ratio of the second moment of area AND the mass, so a ratio of those two things. So the rigidity per mass is just the ratio of the second moment of area, which is the second moment of area?

Comment: No , see my previous comment: :"just multiply A and d. That will give you the ratio kg/m of the beam."

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but I'm wondering if you think the way the question is worded poorly. What you're saying makes sense but it does not seem to answer the question as it does not give a ratio of the second moment of area AND the mass. What I'm asking is do you think that I need to find

The second moment of area 
as well as 
the mass of the beam, which we would find by multiplying Area xDensityxLength

I'm sorry to ask the same question again, but it seems like either I've misunderstood the question or we both have. The people writing them aren't native English speakers, so...

Comment: Basically yes, I have improved my answer

Comment: In case you didn't notice,you should calculate the ratio I/G as mentioned in my edited answer.